# PowerShell redirection of Write-Host to file is not working

Tags: powershell, redirection, stdout

Can someone explain me that behaviour? What is wrong?

```
    PS C:\Scripts\Customer_Shares_Permissions> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.5328
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.5328
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

PS C:\Scripts\Customer_Shares_Permissions> Get-Content .\test.ps1
# Test Write-Host redirecting
Write-Host "Dies ist eine Ausgabe"
Write-Host "Per Write-Host"
Write-Host "auf die Konsole"
Write-Host "Bitte prüfe den redirect in eine Datei"

PS C:\Scripts\Customer_Shares_Permissions> .\test.ps1
Dies ist eine Ausgabe
Per Write-Host
auf die Konsole
Bitte prüfe den redirect in eine Datei

PS C:\Scripts\Customer_Shares_Permissions> .\test.ps1 > test.txt
Dies ist eine Ausgabe
Per Write-Host
auf die Konsole
Bitte prüfe den redirect in eine Datei

PS C:\Scripts\Customer_Shares_Permissions> Get-Content .\test.txt
PS C:\Scripts\Customer_Shares_Permissions>
```

The file `test.txt` get created, but is empty and the output is still displayed on console instead getting directed into the file.

This is not what I expect as behaviour. Where is the problem in my thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Write-Output` as `Write-Host` does not write to a file but to the console.

```
Write-Output "First line" > text.txt 
Write-Output "Second line" >> text.txt
```

The `>>` is use to append the file with new contents.

Comment: puuhhh, that's it?
Thank you.

Comment: It is deeper explained e.g. here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754069/powershell-difference-between-write-host-and-write-output

In a nutshell, Write-Host writes to the console itself. Think of it as a MsgBox in VBScript. Write-Output, on the other hand, writes to the pipeline, so the next command can accept it as its input. You are not required to use Write-Output in order to write objects, as Write-Output is implicitly called for you.

Comment: you don't need `Write-Output` at all, just `"First Line" > text.txt` is enough

Answer (score 3):

The issue is quite basic here - it comes from lack of understanding what [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) does:

> Starting in Windows PowerShell 5.0, `Write-Host` is a wrapper for `Write-Information`. This allows you to use `Write-Host` to emit output to the information stream.

[`Write-Information`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-information) uses the information stream. Now if we take a look at [streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams) documentation:

> 6 | Information stream | PowerShell 5.0 | `Write-Information`

we can see that `6` is the stream number where the action takes place.

That means that to redirect `Write-Host` to a file, you would need to use:

```
.\test.ps1 6>test.txt
```

And before PS 5.0, if anyone is using such outdated version still (7 has been out for a while now), redirection was impossible.

But as the other answer stated, unless you have a purpose to use `Write-Host` specifically, you can just use `Write-Output` to write to standard output stream (success, stream number `1`) instead. Or you can even use implicit output, so just strings, which is assumed to be standard output by PowerShell.